# TypeError: 'ShiftSerializer' object is not callable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do with ModelViewSet. I am facing this error now

Here is my viewset=>

```
class ShiftViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Shift.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShiftSerializer()

    # filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    # filterset_fields = ('shiftid',)    

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def newest(self, request):
        newest = self.get_queryset().order_by('Created_DT').last()
        serializer = self.get_serializer_class()(newest)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def shiftsum(self, request):        
        query = (
                    Shift.objects.values('shiftid')
                        .annotate(shiftdesc=Max('shiftdesc'))
                        .annotate(overnight=Max('overnight'))
                        .annotate(isspecialshift=Max('isspecialshift'))
                        .annotate(ct=Count('*'))  # get count of rows in group
                        .order_by('shiftid')
                        .distinct()
                )
        serializer = ShiftSummarySerializer(query,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def byshiftid(self, request):        
        shiftid = self.request.query_params.get('shiftid',None)
        query = self.get_queryset().filter(shiftid=shiftid)
        serializer = ShiftSerializer(query,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here is my router and url =>

```
router.register('shifts_mas', ShiftViewSet, base_name='shifts')

 path('api/', include(router.urls))
```

Normally I can call like /api/shifts_mas/ and I will get all record of `shift` but just now i got this error and i dont know why. May i know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a serializer class and not an instance of the class as your `serializer_class` attribute

```
serializer_class = ShiftSerializer  # No parenthesis here
```

Comment: @lain, Thanks, At first times, I use like that ShiftSerializer(many=true), I just remove the many=true, forget to remove open-close also. Though it is not a problem. Thank u.I will accept your answer soon.